# Saving to a specific directory

Tags: java, file, text, directory, save

I'm currently trying to save a newly created text file to a directory that the user specifies. However, I don't see how it is possible with this code setup. Where does one specify where file is to be saved?

```
if(arg.equals(Editor.fileLabels[1])){
    if(Editor.VERBOSE)
        System.err.println(Editor.fileLabels[1] + 
                " has been selected");
    filedialog = new FileDialog(editor, "Save File Dialog", FileDialog.SAVE); 
    filedialog.setVisible(true);
    if(Editor.VERBOSE){
        System.err.println("Exited filedialog.setVisible(true);");
        System.err.println("Save file = " + filedialog.getFile());
        System.err.println("Save directory = " + filedialog.getDirectory());
    }
    File file = new File("" + filedialog.getName());
    SimpleFileWriter writer =     SimpleFileWriter.openFileForWriting(filedialog.getFile() + ".txt"); 
    if (writer == null){
        System.out.println("Failed.");
    }
    writer.print("" + this.editor.getTextArea().getText());
    writer.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`FileChooser` and `FileWriter` make things fairly easy, here is the java tutorial:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html
http://www.abbeyworkshop.com/howto/java/writeText/index.html

You call it like this:

```
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();

int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(aComponent);

if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) 
{
    File toSave = fc.getSelectedFile();

    FileWriter outWriter = new FileWriter(toSave);
    PrintWriter outPrinter = new PrintWriter(outWriter);

    outPrinter.println("" + this.editor.getTextArea().getText());
}
else
{
    //user pressed cancel
}
```

Remember that it is the `PrintWriter` class that does the actual printing.

EDIT:

If you want the user to select directories only, call

```
fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
```

before displaying it.  Note that in this case you will have to specify a new File object WITHIN that directory in order to be able to write text to it (attempting to write the text to a directory will result in an IOException).

Comment: In case the OP is not clear.  Using the selected File itself as the argument, will account for both the file name **&** the directory.

Comment: +1, for the link to the file chooser tutorial. -1, for not using the textArea.write(...) method (ie. don't reinvent the wheel).

Comment: Perhaps reinventing in this simple case, but anything beyond just the text area and he'll need the general solution...

Answer (score 0):

> writer.print("" + this.editor.getTextArea().getText());

Don't use methods like that. All text components support a write(...) method. All you have to do is get the File name that you want to write the file to.

Something like:

```
JtextArea textArea = new JTextArea(....);
....
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter( "TextAreaLoad.txt" ); // get the file name from the JFileChooser.
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter( writer );
textArea.write( bw );
bw.close();
```

If you don't know how to use file choosers then read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use File Choosers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html).